# Timeout while accessing https site inside docker container, works fine with http

Tags: docker, ssl, dockerfile

I cannot reach my website inside docker container with SSL. Below is output of `curl -Ls -o /dev/null -v http://docker-mydomain.xyz`.

```
...
...
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=docker-mydomain.xyz
*  start date: Jan 26 07:12:47 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 26 07:12:46 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "docker-mydomain.xyz" matched cert's "docker-mydomain.xyz"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: docker-mydomain.xyz
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

It will stuck on `Accept: */*` process until timeout, however it works fine if I switch to http. The container is set to listen on `8080` port.

`docker ps` output.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                      NAMES
150f5a5c08c4   liso/testdocker   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   6 hours ago   Up 6 hours   127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp   testdocker
```

VirtualHost **outside** docker container.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName docker-mydomain.xyz
    Redirect permanent / https://docker-mydomain.xyz/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName docker-mydomain.xyz    
    ProxyRequests Off    
    <Location />
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    </Location>
    # SSL Location
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/le/docker-mydomain.xyz/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/le/docker-mydomain.xyz/site.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/le/docker-mydomain.xyz/fullchain.cer
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtualhost **inside** docker container.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testdocker
    <Directory /var/www/testdocker/>
         Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I can confirm the website works without problem outside docker container, I have checked apache log inside the container and found no incoming traffic.

---

Feel free to ask anything, I'll be happy to post any logs if needed.

**Website outside docker container works without issue using http/https.**

Comment: The SSL handshake obviously works. So it looks like the forwarding to the inner server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/ hangs. Unfortunately there is nothing known about this server. *"it works fine if I took out the SSL directive"* - it is unclear to me what "SSL directive" you are taking about and what you mean with *"it works fine"*.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I mean if I remove all ssl reference and switch to http (port 80) only in virtualhost, it works without problem— meaning curl able to reach the website and I can visit it through internet browser. As it currently stand, both curl and browser will hang until timeout.

Comment: You mean if you put the __exact__ same Location section (with ProxyPass etc) into the Virtualhost :80 and remove the VirtualHost :443 and the redirect to https, then you can access  the site from outside docker with plain HTTP?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes exactly, Im sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: Please checks your inner application to see if a) it actually gets the request when HTTPS is used and b) it does not behave differently just because the request came from HTTPS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I checked apache inside docker container, can confirm it's not receiving any request in https. Also forgot to mention, If I put the website on the host (outside docker container), it works with or without https.

Comment: In `ProxyPass` directives try using `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: I'm getting 500 internal server error now.

Comment: Does it work for, say, a PNG file? Or have you only tested it for your index.html? (It's possible that there's some .htaccess or something inside your docker project which is trying to redirect you to HTTPS, which obviously won't work because the docker itself only supports HTTP, since the docker doesn't have a `VirtualHost` for HTTPS.) What happens if you open up `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` in your Chrome browser? Does it load correctly, or have infinite redirects to HTTPS, or something else?

Comment: Err. I mean `http://docker-mydomain.xyz:8080`, not `127.0.0.1:8080`, I guess. (Though you might want to check that the firewall is open on port `8080`, otherwise you'll probably just get a boring `Access Denied` when trying to access it directly from the browser.)

Comment: @EliezerBerlin I tried with file and it doesn't work, it still hanging. `curl`-ing to 127.0.0.1:8080 works, also I try open `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in browser, it also works.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin Firewall is turned off

Comment: Have you tried to run curl with --insecure ? to avoid that this is a SSL validation problem

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have:

```
Client (Browser)
       │
       │ HTTPS Request
       ▼
[Reverse Proxy (Apache outside Docker)]
       │ SSL Termination
       │
       │ HTTP Request
       ▼
[Apache Server Inside Docker Container]
       │ Listens on Port 8080
       │
       │ (The request seems to hang here)
       │
       ▼
[Web Application in Docker (Files in /var/www/testdocker)]
```

- A client (like a web browser) initiates an HTTPS request to your domain (`docker-mydomain.xyz`).
- The request reaches your reverse proxy set up with Apache outside the Docker container. Here, SSL termination takes place, converting the HTTPS request into an HTTP request.
- This HTTP request is then forwarded to the Apache server running inside your Docker container, listening on port 8080.
- The Apache server inside the Docker container is supposed to process this HTTP request and fetch the required files from the `/var/www/testdocker` directory to serve the requested web page.
- However, based on your description, the request seems to hang at the Apache server inside the Docker container, and the request doesn't reach the web application files in `/var/www/testdocker`.

That means the interaction between the reverse proxy and the Apache server inside the Docker container is preventing the HTTP request from being processed as expected.

Check first the [`ProxyPreserveHost On` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost): it is set in your `VirtualHost` configuration for port 443. This means that the host header of the incoming requests is preserved when the request is proxied to the backend server. In your case, the Docker container expects HTTP traffic on port 8080. It is possible that preserving the HTTPS host header might be causing issues. You might consider turning it off to see if it resolves the issue.

You also mentioned there is no incoming traffic observed in the Apache log inside the Docker container. That could mean a network or configuration issue in the Apache setup within the container.
Double-check that Apache is indeed running and listening on port 8080 inside the container. You might want to try accessing Apache directly from within the container using `curl` or `wget` to see if it is responding properly to HTTP requests.

From outside the container, use `curl` to directly interact with the Apache server inside the container over HTTP to see if it is reachable. You can run a command similar to below:

```bash
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

If that does not work, take a look at any firewall or security settings preventing the reverse proxy from communicating with the Apache server inside the Docker container over HTTP.

---

> - Firewall is turned off
> - I can confirm that curl-ing directly the container using their port (curl https://127.0.0.1:8080) works without problem.
> - Changing `ProxyPreseveHost On` to `Off` does not have any effect.
> - `openssl s_client -connect docker-mydomain.xyz:443` is stuck for 1 min on Extended master secret: no, then it gets closed and the command end.

With these observations in mind, we can suspect that the issue is probably between the reverse proxy setup and the Docker container. It might be beneficial to review the SSL settings and the proxy directives in the Apache configuration.

- Make sure the `SSLCipherSuite` directive in your Apache configuration is correctly configured and supports the necessary protocols. Sometimes, discrepancies in the SSL configuration can lead to such issues.
- Review the proxy configuration in the `VirtualHost` for port 443. Given that direct curl to the container's port works fine, the issue seems to be in the proxy setup. Consider looking at the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives to ensure they are correctly configured.
- Revisit the Apache error and access logs on the reverse proxy server for any other hints or error messages that might indicate why the connection is being terminated.
- There might be an issue with the SSL handshake. Consider re-evaluating the SSL certificate configurations in your Apache settings.
  As a debugging step, you might try setting up a `VirtualHost` for HTTP (port 80) without SSL to proxy requests to the Docker container, to see if this works without the SSL layer.

If all else fails, as a last resort, consider setting up the reverse proxy configuration from scratch, step by step, testing at each stage to ensure it is working correctly.

Comment: I can confirm that `curl`-ing directly the container using their port (`curl https://127.0.0.1:8080`) works without problem.

Comment: Changing `ProxyPreseveHost On` to `Off` does not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to test the SSL handshake inside your container first.

```
echo | \
    openssl s_client -servername docker-mydomain.xyz -connect docker-mydomain.xyz:443 2>/dev/null | \
    openssl x509 -text
```

or

```
openssl s_client -connect docker-mydomain.xyz:443
```

HTTP works but https doesn't work, it appears to be a TLS/SSL issue. Let's rule out other possibilities first.

Comment: Hello, it's stuck for 1 min on `Extended master secret: no`, then I get `closed` and the command end.

Comment: In the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf file, you can configure the Extended Master Secret (EMS) extension by setting extendedMasterSecret = 1. Alternatively, consider downloading the latest version of OpenSSL. While this might not directly address the issue you've encountered, it can provide more insights into the TLS handshake process. I suspect that the problem may be related to missing TLS components within the container. It's essential to prioritize getting OpenSSL to work correctly as the first step.